# .gitignore, exclude all files in a folder... but keep those sub-folders with a .gitkeep inside it?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to **ignore all files in `log` folder, except for `.gitkeep` files** (I need those files for keeping empty directories):

```
- log
  |- foo.log (should be ignored)
  |- folder1 (should be ignored)
  |- folder2 (keep it because contains a .gitkeep file)
     |- .gitkeep
```

Not working:

```
/log/*
!/log/*/.gitkeep
```

Using `**` doesn't work too:

```
/log/*
!/log/**/.gitkeep
```

Is this possible... without manually exclude each subfolder, like this?

```
/log/folder1/*
/log/folder2/*
!/log/folder2/.gitkeep
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unignore directories ignored with `*`:

```
/log/**
!/log/*/
!/log/*/.gitkeep
```

Without this `git` doesn't even look into ignored subdirectories.

Comment: This doesn't work without adding also `/log/*/*` right?

Comment: Or make the top line `/log/**`.

Answer (score 2):

A variant to @phd 's answer that works in any level of subfolders, and not just the first level of subdirectories:

```
# Ignore all files within a directory (recursively)
/log/**

# But do not ignore any directory or subdirectory it contains
!/log/**/

# Do not ignore a special file name
!.gitkeep
```

This was tested in the following case:

```
.
└── log/
    ├── .gitkeep
    ├── dirA/
    │   ├── dirAA/
    │   │   ├── .gitkeep
    │   │   └── fileAAA.txt
    │   └── fileAA.txt
    ├── dirB/
    │   ├── .gitkeep
    │   └── fileBA.txt
    └── file.txt
```

Now, `git add log/` yields:

```bash
user@machine$ git add log/
user@machine$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   log/.gitkeep
        new file:   log/dirA/dirAA/.gitkeep
        new file:   log/dirB/.gitkeep

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        .gitignore.swp
```

Note: Although `git add` can only add files (and not empty folders), it is important to un-ignore the folders (with `!/log/**/`) because otherwise git won't even be searching the `.gitkeep` files within those folders.

(Also, recall that the meaning of `**` is simply "file path/name that may contain any character including '/'", whereas `*` matches with any character excluding '/'.)